# How to bring back GOOGLE PLAY SERVICES

Tags: google-play-store

NOTE: MY PHONE IS ROOTED.

A few days back my GOOGLE PLAY STORE started showing '"NO CONNECTION...RETRY" even when the phone was connected to WIFI. All other internet using apps worked normally but appstore didnt. SO my friend told me to uninstall the PLAY SERVICES and again insatll it through finding an .apk file of it on internet.I did uninstalled butb i cant find any file to reinstall the play services and my phone is. I tried everything best but couldnt get any solution. Should I go for A factory reset or there is some other solution as well.

Answer (score 1):

[Google Play Services](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms&hl=en&referrer=utm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Dorganic%26utm_term%3Dgoogle+play+services+apk&pcampaignid=APPU_mY98VPHMKYKegwTvioSwAQ) as of Nov. 25, 2014.

This directly from the Play Store. I have used this on a couple of devices. It works. Install like a normal apk.